# How can I make my header smaller on mobile?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm setting up a new website and I want to make my header smaller on mobile. I have tried it with `@media (max-width: 960px)`, but that didn't work.

The website I'm working with is https://www.picture-it-in.org and the header can be seen at the 'About' page (https://www.picture-it-in.org/about).

I'm working with the LeadEngine WordPress theme, and have already installed a child theme.

```css
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    #wrapper > header > div > .entry-header .section-heading{
      padding-top: 29px !important;
      padding-bottom: 29px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class=" ">
    <header class="entry-header single-page-header ">
        <div class="row single-page-heading blog-title-left ">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="section-heading">Pictures</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
 </div>
```

I expected the code to make the header smaller on mobile, but there is no difference after making the adjustments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're targeting the wrong div, and your media query is wrong. This might be what you're after?

```
@media (max-width: 960px){
  header.entry-header.single-page-header {
    padding-top: 29px;
    padding-bottom: 29px;
   }
}
```